# Minimizing the L2 norm of the function gradient.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am a beginner in convex optimization and I have a question about minimizing the norm of the function gradient. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, and I know that the following claim that " $f(x) < f(y)$ if and only if $\lVert \nabla f(x) \rVert_2 < \lVert \nabla f(y) \rVert_2$ " is wrong , e.g. $f$ is a linear function. But I wonder under what circumstances this claim is true. Maybe the function $f$ is strictly convex ?
A proof or a reference to the proof would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such relation. Look at the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} a |x| & \text{ if } x\le 0\\
b|x|  & \text{ if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
This function is convex if $a\ge0$ and $b\ge0$ (it is some kind of absolute value function with different slope left and right from the origin). Now take $x<0<y$. Then $f'(x) - f'(y) = a-b$, which is fixed, but $f(x)-f(y)$ can take any real value.

Of course, the $f$ above is not differentiable. If one replaces the expression $|x|$ by $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ one gets a convex $f$, with essentially the same properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know that this relation cannot hold in all cases. But I'm still curious under what circumstances this relation can be true. For now, I'm considering this case. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly convex function, and $f(x)$ is symmetric about a point $x = x_0$ i.e. $f(x_0 - x) = f(x_0 + x)$ for all $x$. Under this case, I think maybe this relation is correct.